# Is it possible to apply the [ScriptIgnore] attribute at runtime?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

Can I change the field

```
public virtual ClassOne ClassOne { get; set; }
```

to

```
[ScriptIgnore]
public virtual ClassOne ClassOne { get; set; }
```

at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Attributes are part of the produced IL.

You *could* use the reflection API (or the [roslyn CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27746)) to create types at runtime that have this attribute, but you can't simply "inject" it into running code.